# Nested object in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

is it possible to create following schema with mongoose

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("542014e432315e917e7cc335"),
  "displayName": "jimmy",
   ......
  "stats": {
    "2014-10": {
      "documentsCount": NumberInt(1),
      "usedStorage": NumberInt(100),
      "usedBandwidth": NumberInt(250) 
    },
    "2014-11": {
      "documentsCount": NumberInt(1),
      "usedStorage": NumberInt(500),
      "usedBandwidth": NumberInt(150) 
    }
  }
}
```

1. How do declare the 'stats' fields in schema?
2. Is it possible to find necessary subdocument in 'stats' by keyname
   and update it or insert new (if it doesn't exist)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using SchemaTypes or SubSchema

See @ http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html